# Understanding graphical meaning of tangent line in optimization problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, optimization, linear-programming

In a trivial optimization problem where dependent variable $y(x_b)$ is a curve, I'm seeking the value of $x_b$ that minimizes $\frac{y(x_b)}{x_b-x_a}$,where constant $x_a>0$. The solution has been graphically given as the value where a diagonal line starting at $x_a$ is tangent to $y(x_b)$. Ex., when $y(x_b)=x_b^2$ and $x_a=0.5$, the optimized $x_b=1$.

I have difficulty understanding why this is true, i.e., the logical steps behind the equivalences supporting the solution, either via calculus, geometric, or algebraic reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{y(x_b)}{x_b-x_a}$ is the slope of the tangent line to the curve at $(x_b,y(x_b))$. Hence $y'(x_b)=\frac{y(x_b)}{x_b-x_a}.$

---

We have to minimize $\frac{y(x)}{x-x_a}$. So, take its derivative with respect to $x$ and set it equal with $0$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{y(x)}{x-x_a}=\frac{y'(x)(x-x_a)-y(x)}{(x-x_a)^2}=0.$$

Since $y'(x_b)=\frac{y(x_b)}{x_b-x_a}$, $x_b$ solves this equation. ($x_b\not=x_a)$.